# Триггерная функция в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Надо, чтоб при создании записи в таблице А, автоматически создавалась запись в таблице Б, и в таблицу А записывался id записи таблицы Б.
Для таблицы создаю триггер AFTER INSERT, и в качестве обработчика функцию:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
    _texts_id int2:= to_number(INSERT INTO texts VALUES (nextval('texts_seq'::regclass)) RETURNING texts_id);
BEGIN
    NEW.texts_id := _texts_id;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Но при исполнении запроса выскакивает ошибка:

```
[Err] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO"
LINE 5:  _texts_id int2:= to_number(INSERT INTO texts VALUES (nextva...
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что в секции declare можно выполнять insert. может это выполнить после слова begin. И когда вы разберетесь с insert вам надо будет переделать триггер на before. Потому как триггер after уже не может изменить какие либо данные в таблице, т.к. срабатывает уже после записи

Comment: И я не знаю синтаксиса постгресса, но мне кажется, что если insert с таким returning не работает, то надо сначала в переменную получить nextval, выполнить insert с id из этой переменной и присвоить ее new....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем примере некорректно изпользуется функция to_number ([ссылка на документацию](https://www.postgrespro.ru/doc/functions-formatting.html))

И можно обойтись без лишних переменных и функций.

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_trigger()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
        NEW.texts_id := nextval('texts_seq' ::regclass);
        INSERT INTO texts(a) VALUES (NEW.texts_id);
        RETURN NEW;
    END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```